# Vue-test-utils doesn't wait for the response from the API request

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, axios

I've been really struggling to do something very simple. I have to write some tests for a Vue application.

The scenario I want to test is the following:

1. The user fills in a form
2. The user submits the form
3. The values from the form are sent to the backend in one object
4. The server responds with an object containing the fields of the object it has received in the request (plus some new fields).
5. The Vue app stores the result in the Vuex store

I want my test to check if, after the form has been validated, the request is made and the returned values are properly stored in the store.

This is super basic, but for some reason I can't get the test to work.

I have a globally registered component that makes axios accessible by using `this.api`.
So in my test, I have the following (the file is simplified for this post):

```js
...
import axios from 'axios';
import AxiosMockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises';

// This is the axios setup used in the components
import api from '../../src/mixins/api';

// Components
import MyComponent from '../component.vue';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  // Set up the local vue
  ...

  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
    localVue,
    ...
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'some/url/',
    });
    wrapper.vm.api = new AxiosMockAdapter(instance);
    wrapper.vm.api.onPost('url/').replyOnce(201, { data: { foo: 'bar' } });
  });

  it('should retrieve the data', async () => {
     wrapper.find('#submit').trigger('click');

    await flushPromises();
    expect(wrapper.vm.$store.state.foo !== undefined).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

But the test isn't successful. I think the request is made properly, but by the time the test reaches its end the response hasn't be received yet. And this is despite using `flushPromises()`. I also tried to use `setTimeout` but with no success neither.

I'm new to unit testing (especially on front end apps) and I have no idea what else to try. Nothng works... It's very frustrating because what I'm tryng to do is pretty straight forward and basic.

Anyone has an idea what to do ?

Comment: if click triggers re-render you can simply use `Vue.nextTick(function () {})` to wait.

Comment: flushPromises just provides one-tick delay, it's not magical. *I also tried to use setTimeout but with no success neither* - how much? Then the problem is likely not a race condition but something else. This isn't unit but integration test. You test several units (component, store, api) and don't know which of them causes the problem. It's a good practice to move business logic to a store so it could be tested separately from UI. It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing all relevant code. It's not known if there really was a request to `url/`, for starters. Try to add some spies.

Comment: Ok so you're telling me I should distinguish between testing units like functions (which is basically what I'm trying to do) and testing if the interface works correctly. Then is it a good practice to place *all important* API calls to the store (in actions) so they can be tested in units ?

Comment: @EstusFlask *As for `setTimeout` the problem was that it never entered the callback so the test would succeed no matter what.

Comment: Yes, it's generally a good practice, known as fat model in MVC/MVVM. How exactly did you use setTimeout? The only ways for setTimeout to not enter the callback is when setTimeout wasn't called at all or Node process exited, can also look like that if the test ended before a timeout, i.e. `done` wasn't used. What I meant is `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))` instead of flushPromises, this way you can be sure that there is no race condition in promises.